# Assert.ThrowsException in async function unit test?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, assert

I try to make a test method to test some simple data downloading. I made a test case in which downloading should fail with HttpRequestException. When testing its non-async version, test works great and passes, but when testing its asnyc version, it fails.

What is the trick about using Assert.ThrowsException in case of async/await methods?

```
[TestMethod]
public void FooAsync_Test()
{
    Assert.ThrowsException<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException>
        (async () => await _dataFetcher.GetDataAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAICT, Microsoft just forgot to include it. It should certainly be there IMO (if you agree, [vote on UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3401331-add-an-async-compatible-assert-throwsexception)).

In the meantime, you can use the method below. It's from the `AsyncAssert` class in [my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/). I'm planning to release `AsyncAssert` as a NuGet library in the near future, but for now you can just put this in your test class:

```
public static async Task ThrowsAsync<TException>(Func<Task> action, bool allowDerivedTypes = true)
{
    try
    {
        await action();
        Assert.Fail("Delegate did not throw expected exception " + typeof(TException).Name + ".");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (allowDerivedTypes && !(ex is TException))
            Assert.Fail("Delegate threw exception of type " + ex.GetType().Name + ", but " + typeof(TException).Name + " or a derived type was expected.");
        if (!allowDerivedTypes && ex.GetType() != typeof(TException))
            Assert.Fail("Delegate threw exception of type " + ex.GetType().Name + ", but " + typeof(TException).Name + " was expected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have also implemented a workaround similar to yours, but I hoped that could be an out-of-the-box Microsoft solution. Thanks, to make it clear they have not done it yet!

Comment: Still seems to be a problem in VS 2013.

Comment: MSTest only supports `ThrowsAsync` (or whatever they call it) for Windows Store projects. You'll have to use your own implementation elsewhere.

Comment: Update: MSTestV2 now supports both `Assert.ThrowsException<T>` and `Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<T>` - see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2017/02/25/mstest-v2-now-and-ahead/

Comment: @Quango: Yes! Half a decade later... after practically everyone has moved to xUnit... including the primary MS .NET teams... Better late than never, I guess! :)

Answer (score 8):

**Context:** According to your description, your test fails.

**Solution:** Another alternative (also mentioned by @quango) to solve this is:

```
[TestMethod]
public void FooAsync_Test() {
    await Assert.ThrowsExceptionAsync<HttpRequestException>(() => _dataFetcher.GetDataAsync());
}
```

Solution using xUnit:

```
[Fact]
public async void FooAsync_Test() {
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<HttpRequestException>(() => _dataFetcher.GetDataAsync());
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Following works fine to me:

```
Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(() => class.AsyncMethod(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```